# Do math arithmetic on busybox sh

Tags: shell, busybox

I have string variables `MIN` and `SEC` (minute and seconds):

```
MIN="1"
SEC="34"
```

I want to do calculations on these:

```
TOTSEC = MIN*60 + SEC
```

I tried:

```
expr $SEC + $MIN * 60
```

Result:

```
expr: non-numeric argument
```

Let it be known I am running `busybox` on a custom microcomputer and so have no access to `bash`, `bc`, and that other solution provides.

Comment: You probably just need to escape the `*` i.e. `expr $SEC + $MIN \* 60`

Answer (score 11):

`busybox` uses `ash`, so you can use:

```
MIN=1 SEC=34 busybox sh -c 'echo "$(( MIN*60 + SEC ))"'
94
```

Or with `expr`:

```
MIN=1 SEC=34 busybox sh -c 'expr " $MIN" \* 60 + "$SEC"'
94
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. But I ended up using awk. TOTSEC=\`awk "BEGIN {print $SEC+($MIN*60)}"\`